# What is the format used for "Expires" field in signed url format -aws s3?

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am using unity's WWW class to download game assets from amazon server.I was going through signed url format to be used to access the file.I want to know what is the Date-Time format used in the "Expires" field.The format of signed url is in link http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-files.html .I tried using MMddhhmmyy format.It did not work for me.

Comment: When I said you need to ask that question on a website, I actually meant on the Amazon website. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=612247. They know more about this than anybody else.

Comment: I asked one hour ago.Nobody replied. :(

Comment: Ok. I think you have an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation states](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html) that `Expires` is the

> date and time in [Unix time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (in seconds) and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

The example URL `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject.ext?AWSAccessKeyId =ALSECKCKDKMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1301234062&Signature=ssmu34aCsECO8%2F6vHDdf9u0TCcU%3D` would therefore indicate a date of Sun, 27 Mar 2011 13:54:22.

Comment: Hey can you translate that in MMddhhmmyy format? To me that looks like ddmmyyhhmmss....13 is hour, 54 is minutes and 22 is seconds?

Comment: Yup, Sunday, March 27th 2011, 1:54 and 22 seconds PM

Comment: Thank you Bart.Works for me..!!